# Topological rather than metric based machine learning theory?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, topologies

The first notion of continuity in a math class is usually the one based on metric spaces. In particular, the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition of continuity.

But in topology, a more general notion of continuity is defined.

In the context of machine learning, and computational learning theory, I've encountered $\epsilon, \delta$ based results (e.g. in PAC learning, and function approximation theorems for neural nets).

Are there "topological" style theorems about machine learning/computational learning theory, that don't make use of $\epsilon$'s and $\delta$'s?

Answer (score 6):

> Are there "topological" style theorems about machine
>   learning/computational learning theory, that don't make use of
>   $\epsilon$'s and $\delta$'s?

I think it's illustrative to mention why most ML uses "$\epsilon$'s and $\delta$'s" - that's because it's based on statistics, and if you actually use statistics for anything, you need guarantees for **finite samples**, not for how stuff behaves in the limit.

I recall single theorem that may actually look like what you've described:
[On Fiber Diameters of Continuous Maps](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~mlazar/fibers.pdf) uses Borsuk-Ulam theorem to establish that every dimensionality reduction method necessarily 'glues together' arbitrarily distant points.

If on the other hand you're asking about interesting topological ideas in data science/ML, then you could check these ones out:

- [Topological Data Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_data_analysis)
- [UMAP algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03426)

I think that you should also find [Topological and Geometric Data Reduction and Visualization](https://yao-lab.github.io/2019_csic5011/) course interesting.